# PHP / Laravel - Foreach store into database (\Grammar::parameterize() error)

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array, which looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  "field" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "fromName"
    1 => "from"
  ]
  "operator" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "="
    1 => "="
  ]
  "value" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Oliver"
    1 => "oliver@mywebsite.com"
  ]
]
```

I am trying to save the above array, into my database table called `email_rules`:

[image: My database table]

Below is my code.

`StreamEmailRulesController.php`:

```
public function store(Stream $stream)
{
    //Validate the request.
    //Validate the request.
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'field' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'field.*' => [
            'required', 'string',
            Rule::in(['fromName', 'from']),
        ],
        'operator' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'operator.*' => [
            'required', 'string',
            Rule::in(['=', '!=', 'matches']),
        ],
        'value' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'value.*' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
    ]);

    //Add the document to the database.
    $stream->addRules($attributes);

    //Return back.
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Now the `$stream->addRules()` function is responsible for saving the data to the database.

`Stream.php`:

```
/**
* A stream can have many rules.
*/
public function rules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EmailRule::class);
}


/**
 * Add Email Rules(s) to the stream
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function addRules(array $attributes)
{
    return $this->rules()->create($attributes);
}
```

Now, above does not work. I get below error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, int given,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Laravels `create` or `createMany` expect an array with key => pair values, where the key corresponds to the database columns.

[**This article**](https://adamwathan.me/2016/04/06/cleaning-up-form-input-with-transpose/) from Adam Wathan helped me out a lot.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
  $requestData = collect(request()->only('field', 'operator', 'value'));
  $rules = $requestData->transpose()->map(function ($ruleData) {
         return new EmailRule([
             'field' => $ruleData[0],
             'operator' => $ruleData[1],
             'value' => $ruleData[2],
         ]);
  })->toArray();

  //Add the rules to the database.
  $stream->addRules($rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dump $attributes you may be getting an int (bool) as a pass or fail or even json, depending on what's going in, from the validation.  This might just be a matter of changing syntax from

```
 $attributes = request()->validate([...
```

to

```
$attributes= $this->validate(request(), [...
```

I believe your issue is that you're trying to save an array as a singular value.  IE those attributes need to be iterated over to create a new set of rules *for each one*, instead.  Normally, I'd expect to see the array ready to create individual objects.  In this case, though it looks like it is structured to create *individual fields* (field, operator, value), so looping through those may not do what you wish either -- it provides multiple fields to the create construct, rather than a full set of object params for a new rule().  I think Laravel is hinting that you may wish to change your request/return structure to match the model format.

Comment: The dump is after the validation. Changing it to `$this->validate..` does not work

Comment: Ah!  I understand now.  I think I see the problem.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the array structure. Can you modify the array to?:

```
[
   [
   "field" => "fromName",
   "operator" => "=",
   "value" => "Oliver"
   ],
   [
   "field" => "from",
   "operator" => "=",
   "value" => "oliver@mywebsite.com"
   ],
]
```

---

**EDIT**:
In the Controller add a loop like this:

```
...
foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $data [$k][$key] = $v;
    }
}

//Add the document to the database.
$stream->addRules($data);
```

Comment: The array is from Laravels default `request()`.

Comment: @oliverbj sorry my bad english. maybe is there a better way than nested foreach, but you can try like in the edit of my answer

Comment: @Pablo - your English is fine.  And your answer is good.  I think we're both pointing to the same error.